# Select unique members from a set by weighted categories/properties

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a collection of objects (5000+) with 7 different properties. Two properties are tertiary the rest are binary. Each object have all 7 properties specified. It is possible that in some scenarios binary property may become unary.

Once in awhile I need to select top N random objects from this collection weighted by the frequency of a label in each category against the objects' total.

Currently, I have all data in sql server table as object, propertyMask pairs; however, I can reorganize that any other way necessary.

Examples:

1. black blue yellow  (1,2,4)
2. circle square triangle (8,16,32)
3. solid color/meshed color (64)
4. dashed contour/no contour (128)
5. etc. (256)

The data is :

```
object1|9   <-      1001 black circle only (all other properties are 0)
object2|81  <-  101 0001 black square with solid color (all other properties are 0)
object3|148 <- 1001 0100 yellow square with dashed contour
etc.
```

Say, I end up with 1k objects with 600 black, 300 yellow and 100 blue objects. And I need to select top 10 objects. If I just consider one property, I'll just take any 6 black, 3 yellow and 1 blue objects. But I have 6 other properties to consider and ensure I have right amount of circles, squares and triangles. Etc. At this point I don't even know how to approach this problem.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

***EDIT:**

I repopulated data in the following format

```
name | att1 | att2 | ...
obj1 |  1   |   8  | ...
obj2 |  2   |   16 | ...
obj3 |  1   |   32 | ...
```

Is there a way to select TOP N objects weighted by the frequency of each attribute? I have 7 attributes for each objects; no Null values.

Thanks!

Comment: NP-hard by reduction from 3D matching. Can you tolerate some approximation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's messy, it does not always fetch the exact number of rows required or an perfect distribution but it comes pretty darn close.

So how does it work:

- ValuesPivotted: pivot all the distinct values and give each row a random rownumber
- TargetDistribution: for each distinct value determine how many you need
- SelectRows: go through each row in ValuesPivotted on a per row basis see if the row is to be skipped because it would otherwise breach an target for an distinct value. Otherwise increment the Sum for each value applicable for that row.

---

```
DECLARE @TargetRowNum INT = 100;

WITH ValuesPivotted AS(
    SELECT O.id
         , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID())
         , [0] =   CASE WHEN O.atr1 = 0   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
         , [1] =   CASE WHEN O.atr1 = 1   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
         , [2] =   CASE WHEN O.atr1 = 2   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
         , [4] =   CASE WHEN O.atr2 = 4   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
         , [8] =   CASE WHEN O.atr2 = 8   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
         , [16] =  CASE WHEN O.atr3 = 16  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
         , [32] =  CASE WHEN O.atr3 = 32  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
         , [64] =  CASE WHEN O.atr4 = 64  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
         , [128] = CASE WHEN O.atr4 = 128 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    FROM dbo.objects AS O
),
TargetDistribution AS (
    SELECT Target0   = ROUND(CAST(SUM([0]  ) AS FLOAT) / COUNT(*) * @TargetRowNum, 0)
         , Target1   = ROUND(CAST(SUM([1]  ) AS FLOAT) / COUNT(*) * @TargetRowNum, 0)
         , Target2   = ROUND(CAST(SUM([2]  ) AS FLOAT) / COUNT(*) * @TargetRowNum, 0)
         , Target4   = ROUND(CAST(SUM([4]  ) AS FLOAT) / COUNT(*) * @TargetRowNum, 0)
         , Target8   = ROUND(CAST(SUM([8]  ) AS FLOAT) / COUNT(*) * @TargetRowNum, 0)
         , Target16  = ROUND(CAST(SUM([16] ) AS FLOAT) / COUNT(*) * @TargetRowNum, 0)
         , Target32  = ROUND(CAST(SUM([32] ) AS FLOAT) / COUNT(*) * @TargetRowNum, 0)
         , Target64  = ROUND(CAST(SUM([64] ) AS FLOAT) / COUNT(*) * @TargetRowNum, 0)
         , Target128 = ROUND(CAST(SUM([128]) AS FLOAT) / COUNT(*) * @TargetRowNum, 0)
    FROM ValuesPivotted
),
SelectRows AS(
    SELECT VP.id
         , RowNum
         , KeepRow = 1
         , Target0    , Sum0   = [0]
         , Target1    , Sum1   = [1]
         , Target2    , Sum2   = [2]
         , Target4    , Sum4   = [4]
         , Target8    , Sum8   = [8]
         , Target16   , Sum16  = [16]
         , Target32   , Sum32  = [32]
         , Target64   , Sum64  = [64]
         , Target128  , Sum128 = [128]
    FROM ValuesPivotted AS VP
        CROSS JOIN TargetDistribution AS TD
    WHERE VP.RowNum = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
           VP.id
         , VP.RowNum
         , KeepRow = ISNULL(SkipRow.Value, 1)
         , Target0    , Sum0   = Sum0   + ISNULL(SkipRow.Value, [0]  )
         , Target1    , Sum1   = Sum1   + ISNULL(SkipRow.Value, [1]  )
         , Target2    , Sum2   = Sum2   + ISNULL(SkipRow.Value, [2]  )
         , Target4    , Sum4   = Sum4   + ISNULL(SkipRow.Value, [4]  )
         , Target8    , Sum8   = Sum8   + ISNULL(SkipRow.Value, [8]  )
         , Target16   , Sum16  = Sum16  + ISNULL(SkipRow.Value, [16] )
         , Target32   , Sum32  = Sum32  + ISNULL(SkipRow.Value, [32] )
         , Target64   , Sum64  = Sum64  + ISNULL(SkipRow.Value, [64] )
         , Target128  , Sum128 = Sum128 + ISNULL(SkipRow.Value, [128])
    FROM SelectRows AS SR
        INNER JOIN ValuesPivotted AS VP
            ON VP.RowNum = SR.RowNum + 1
        CROSS APPLY(
            SELECT  Value = 
                CASE WHEN   Sum0   + [0]   <= Target0 
                        AND Sum1   + [1]   <= Target1 
                        AND Sum2   + [2]   <= Target2 
                        AND Sum4   + [4]   <= Target4 
                        AND Sum8   + [8]   <= Target8 
                        AND Sum16  + [16]  <= Target16
                        AND Sum32  + [32]  <= Target32
                        AND Sum64  + [64]  <= Target64
                        AND Sum128 + [128] <= Target128
                    THEN NULL ELSE 0 END
        ) AS SkipRow
    WHERE  Sum0   < Target0 
        OR Sum1   < Target1 
        OR Sum2   < Target2 
        OR Sum4   < Target4 
        OR Sum8   < Target8 
        OR Sum16  < Target16
        OR Sum32  < Target32
        OR Sum64  < Target64
        OR Sum128 < Target128
)
SELECT O.*
FROM SelectRows AS SR
    INNER JOIN dbo.objects AS O
        ON SR.id = O.id
WHERE SR.KeepRow = 1
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

**EDIT:** The WHERE clause in SelectRows did not do what it was supposed to, stop the recursion when all targets were met, now it does.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what I needed! Approximate output is not a problem as long as weights are correct. And they seem to be so :)